# HIbernate 4.2 No active transaction for PuId

Tags: transactions, jta, websphere-8, hibernate-4.x

I have web application with JPA (Hibernate 4.2), JavaEE 7 which is running on WebSphere 8.5. I want to avoid using EJB in my app. And when I am trying to persist changes i get javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No active transaction for PuId. I hoped that websphere would manage transactions. On wildfly 8.0 everything works fine.

**My persistence.xml**:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<persistence version="2.0"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
                                 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">

    <persistence-unit name="org.jbpm.domain" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/MyApp</jta-data-source>
       <class>Diagram</class>

        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="3"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.WebSphereExtendedJtaPlatform" />
            <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value="false"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

And **class** where I`m trying to persist changes:

```java
    import javax.inject.Inject;
    import javax.inject.Named;
    import javax.transaction.Transactional;

    @Transactional
    @Named
    class PersistentAssetStorage {
      @Inject
        private EntityManager em;

         public long saveProcessDefinition(final Diagram diagram) {
         em.persist(diagram);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebSphere 8.5.5 is unfortunately only Java EE 6 compliant (not yet 7), so it doesn't understand `@Transactional`. For WebSphere 8.5.5 you will have to wrap it in the stateless EJB. Add `@Stateless` instead of `@Transactional` and it should work. WebSphere supports EJBs in web module, so you will not have to create separate EJB module.

Comment: You could try it on the WebSphere Liberty profile 8.5.5.6 and higher, which fully supports Java EE 7.